# App update rejected in Google Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

So, I made an update in my android app and uploaded the new APK file in the console. Unfortunately, I got this after a few hours

[image: Google Console Message]

I am using firebase, so maybe that's why I get this problem. Here is my manifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="theodosios.tziomakas.news">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <!--Disable Analytics collection -->
        <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />


        <activity android:name="theodosios.tziomakas.news.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="theodosios.tziomakas.news.StartActivity"
            />
        <activity
            android:name="theodosios.tziomakas.news.RegisterActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="theodosios.tziomakas.news.StartActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="theodosios.tziomakas.news.LoginActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="theodosios.tziomakas.news.StartActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="theodosios.tziomakas.news.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="theodosios.tziomakas.news.LoginActivity" />

        <receiver android:name="theodosios.tziomakas.news.widget.NewsAppWidgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/news_app_widget_info" />
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="theodosios.tziomakas.news.widget.UpdateNewsWidgetService" />
        <service
            android:name="theodosios.tziomakas.news.widget.GridWidgetService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />

        <activity
            android:name="theodosios.tziomakas.news.DetailActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="theodosios.tziomakas.news.MainActivity" />

        <provider
            android:name="theodosios.tziomakas.news.data.FavouriteProvider"
            android:authorities="theodosios.tziomakas.news"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="theodosios.tziomakas.news.FavouriteNewsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="theodosios.tziomakas.news.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name="theodosios.tziomakas.news.CommentActivity" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you follow these policies listed here [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9899816/)

Also read all these and make change to your app if you app did not follow any of these policy [link](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/)

As in the email they do not mention the reason for rejection clearly. So you have to hit and try what changes you made in this app which are agains the policy.
Before submiting another update check your dashboard of that app, if previous app is still under processing or not. If it is still under update process. Do not submit another update. Wait for sometime to reflect some changes.

After making changes in your app after reading the policies then make new update. Now after update rejection this new update will take 7 to 10 days. Be calm and have patience.

Bonus tip: Also make sure your app store listing do not go against any policy. **SO make sure you are not using any icon, discription or short discription which are related to any brand like youtube, facebook, whatsapp any brand name should not be there.** Also your long discription should be readable like a normal paragraph and it should not be spammy which is filled with full of tags only.